# make Reminder set checkbox from Task under Activity as False (default)

Tags: tasks, activity

I was trying to make this Reminder Set default value as False or unchecked
can someone help me out how it can be done?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are fields on the User object that control this default:
USERPREFERENCESEVENTREMINDERSCHECKBOXDEFAULT
USERPREFERENCESTASKREMINDERSCHECKBOXDEFAULT

You can update the field from TRUE to FALSE using DataLoader.
I don't believe you can set the default for new users (would need to update via DataLoader for each one).

Users can set the option on their own:

1. Personal Setup => My Personal Information => Reminders
2. Uncheck the checkbox for: "By default, set reminder on Tasks to:"